# How to Salvage Damaged AWS Amplify Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I have started an amplify project following this [tutorial](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react) and create-react-app, and have progressed through the authentication
setup steps without issue.

I then attempted to add a REST API endpoint that allows me to POST/PUT a record in DynamoDB. This also worked out-of-the-box.

However, I realized that I needed to change the names of some of the dynamodb fields. The changes that I made are just renaming fields, like the diff below (from `amplify/backend/storage/mytable/parameters.json`):

```
 {
     "tableName": "mytable",
-    "partitionKeyName": "user_id",
+    "partitionKeyName": "userId",
     "partitionKeyType": "S",
-    "sortKeyName": "lesson_id",
+    "sortKeyName": "lessonId",
     "sortKeyType": "S"
 }
```

This change, while small, caused subsequent `amplify push` attempts to fail with the following error:

```
UPDATE_FAILED               DynamoDBTable                                                       AWS::DynamoDB::Table       Tue Mar 05 2019 16:36:25 GMT-0600 (CST) CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename mytable-dev and update the stack again.
```

I then (foolishly, I know) deleted the cloudformation stack associated with this resource, thinking that this would allow me to recreate it from scratch:

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name ${DYNAMODB_STACK_NAME}
```

However, I still cannot `amplify push`, as now I receive this error:

```
UPDATE_FAILED      storagefactUserCellState AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Tue Mar 05 2019 16:40:20 GMT-0600 (CST) Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:... is in DELETE_COMPLETE state and can not be updated.
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to salvage this project (by allowing me to create the dynamodb table) without recreating everything from scratch? I'm going to try the method [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/549) but this seems like a rough thing to do going forward.
2. What is the best-practice way to perform these types of table customizations/alterations so that I do not encounter this sort of problem in the future? I think I'm just doing things wrong because I'm used to the k8s world where putting yaml files under git and using `kubectl apply` is enough to recover from most mistakes, but a lot of the amplify files are `.gitignore`d and the cloud resources seem more brittle, so I'm not sure how to make things robust and safe within this ecosystem.

Comment: I had the same problem. Twice! :-)
I also have little experience with Amplify, fortunately much more with Cloudformation. Figuring this out and create a solution is on my top priorities list. 
Amplify seems only be able to update the stacks, not re-create them. So, for me this is only nice to quickly bootstrap. Afterwards, you'll extract the Cloudformation templates and maintain it manually.